# Adding date and Item to list from user input

Tags: python

Help with inserting current date and new Item

Can anyone Help to insert current date with new item from user-input
I am having trouble with the date mostly and keeping new item stored for 
future input

Heres list and append to create a list from user input:

```
while True:
    try:
        results7 = []
        userInput = str(input('Please enter number\n'))
        results7.append(userInput)
        print(results7)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter Numbers only here')
```

Here is where I am trying to insert new item to a

```
 a = [['Thu', '06', 'Jul', '2017', '221', '5875'], 
      ['Fri', '07', 'Jul', '2017', '134', '0249']]
 b = a[0][:]
 c = b.insert(0, b[0:3] + results7)
 print c
```

When `userInput` = 323, I would like `a` to be

```
[
 ['Thu', '06', 'Jul', '2017', '221', '5875'], 
 ['Fri', '07', 'Jul', '2017', '134', '0249'],
 ['Sat', '08', 'Jul', '2017','323']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to format a date object.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%a %d %b %Y").split(" ")
a.insert(0, date + [userInput])
```